# dax fails in excel but not in power bi?

Tags: excel, powerbi, dax, powerpivot

Whenever I consume my model from excel, if I put the next measure it crashes:

```
IF

(

NOT [Measure1] < 0,

DIVIDE ( [Measure2], [Measure1])
)
```

Why is this happening?

(it works fine in power bi desktop!)

Answer (score 2):

DAX in Excel and Power BI are not *exactly* the same. However, your expression is clumsy, as DIVIDE takes care of any division by zero itself and returns BLANK() or an alternate result in case.

```
DIVIDE(<numerator>, <denominator> [,<alternateresult>])
```

But in your case it rather looks like one of the undisclosed mesures are causing the problem.